# How to save a variable to a text file? (Python 3.11.1)

Tags: python

Newbie student coder, trying out a practice where I calculate the hypotenuse of a right triangle from two values of a text file (the sides of the triangle), then saving it. Basically taking two values listed from a text file, calculating hypotenuse, saving the two values and the hypotenuse back into the same text file.
So far, I've been able to implement a module that calculates the hypotenuse in my program, and get my program to read the text file and calculate the hypotenuse. I've managed to get it displayed on the Idle application, but when I try saving the values (side lengths and calculated hypotenuse) back into the text file, I can save the previously listed values okay, but I can't seem to get the hypotenuse calculated to properly save on it.
It saves on my text file as <bound method TriangleTxtLoad.add_hypotenuse of <**main**.TriangleTxtLoad object at 0x000002330DE4B590>>

I don't know what I am doing wrong?

Hypotenuse Calculation Module (called my_module):

```
#Imports
import math

#Class
class RightTriangle:

    def __init__(self, side_01, side_02):
        self.side_01 = side_01
        self.side_02 = side_02

    def __str__(self):
        triangle_values = f"side_01 = {self.side_01} side_02 = {self.side_02}"             
        return triangle_values

    def calculate_hypotenuse(self):
        return float(math.sqrt(math.pow(self.side_01, 2) + math.pow(self.side_02, 2)))
```

Here's the program I made to read and save variables to a text file:

```
#Imports
from my_module import *

#Class for Txt file
class TriangleTxtLoad:

    def __init__(self):
        self.triangle_measurements = input("Enter the name of the text file with the triangle measurements: ")
        measurement_file = open(self.triangle_measurements, "r")
        self.side_01 = float(measurement_file.readline())
        self.side_02 = float(measurement_file.readline())
        measurement_file.close()

    def __str__(self):
        triangle_values = f'''
                          side_01 = {self.side_01}
                          side_02 = {self.side_02}
                          '''
        return triangle_values

    def add_hypotenuse(self):
        triangle = RightTriangle(self.side_01, self.side_02)
        hypotenuse = triangle.calculate_hypotenuse()
        print(f"The hypotenuse of the triangle with these side lengths is {hypotenuse}")

    def save_measurements(self):
        measurement_file = open(self.triangle_measurements, mode='w')
        measurement_file.write(str(self.side_01))
        measurement_file.write("\n")
        measurement_file.write(str(self.side_02))
        measurement_file.write("\n")
        measurement_file.write(str(self.add_hypotenuse))
        measurement_file.write("\n")
        measurement_file.close()


print()
myTriangle = TriangleTxtLoad()
print(f"Side 1 is {myTriangle.side_01}")
print(f"Side 2 is {myTriangle.side_02}")
myTriangle.add_hypotenuse()
print(myTriangle)
myTriangle.save_measurements()
```

Comment: Typo: `self.add_hypotenuse` is the method object. You probably meant to call it: `self.add_hypotenuse()`

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
measurement_file.write(str(self.add_hypotenuse))
```

needs to be replaced with

```
measurement_file.write(str(self.add_hypotenuse()))
```

`self.add_hypotenuse` is a function, to produce a result it has to be called with `()`.